# Group and manipulate based on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, group-by

I have a table that inserts a row when a certain function is used on the site and stamps the date.

```
code-/----date----/--type
-----/------------/------
--1--/--2012-2-1--/-used
--1--/--2012-2-3--/-saved
--1--/--2012-1-3--/-printed
--2--/--2012-2-1--/-used
--2--/--2012-2-2--/-printed
```

I have to report the number of times code 1 was (printed or saved or used) today, or yesterday, or last month (date range)

I am starting with this:

```
$stat_query = mysql_query("SELECT code, type, date FROM tracking WHERE code IN ('$htL','$htG','$htR') GROUP BY code, type, date");
```

I use the IN operand because each user has 3 codes to track with limitless date entries for each type.

I really am lost as to what to do here.

Comment: So you need to return the number of times a certain `code` is there for a date range?  Do you need to separate out the count by `type`?

Comment: yes, so code one type used has 7 entries today or 20 entries in the last 7 days or other date range..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to construct the date ranges and modify the query.  Below is an example of showing the count for `code` in the past day:

```
SELECT `code`, COUNT(`code`) as code_cnt 
FROM tracking 
WHERE 
    `code` IN ('$htL','$htG','$htR') AND
    `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND now()
GROUP BY `code`
```

Check out the [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) documentation for further help

Answer (score 0):

**GROUP BY code, type, date** in this example makes it to return only one record. Because all code rows would be summerized in distinct output row, also type would be reduce more and more. Please check your GROUP BY fields.

Comment: how would you retrieve the counts so that you could easily display the number of entries for any given date range?